# How can I index the arraylist by a long?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have filled an `arraylist<string>` with 20 lacs strings. If I want to iterate like this,

```
for(long i=0;arrlist.size();i++{
   arrlist.get(i);  

}
```

But, `arrlist.get()` doesn't support index as long. Moreover, I cannot use iterator, so, how do I iterate without an  `Iterator`? Pleas don't ask why I'm not using iterator.

Comment: The title of your question does not seem to match the actual question.

Comment: You can well use int in your loop. The arraylist anyway can not hold number of elements that an int cannot index.

Answer (score 4):

From your question it seems you are trying to iterate over each element. Note that for this purpose you may use the nicer for loop:

```
for(String element: arrlist) {
   // Do whatever you want with your element
}
```

Comment: Uuuuh - that's "using an iterator" ... ;-)

Comment: Sure it does. The "I cannot use iterator" applies even for the underneath solutions? I understood he didn't want to create the iterator himself ...

Comment: @Jan - the comment targeted the OP ;) +1 from me to show him a good solution (as long as he doesn't tell us *why* he *has to* avoid iterators!)

Comment: Thank for all your suggestions. But the main problem is that I need to access the arraylist elements sequentially and its taking every long coz I'm comparing those elements too.

Comment: You are probably aware that there are classes like TreeSet which takes care about the comparison? As others pointed out there is no point using long since arrylist will never hold more elements than int can index. With being certain of that just cast it to int if you must.

Comment: Thank you! I got that. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think `arrlist.get((int) i)` should work.  Or you could just declare `i` as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList#size()` doesn't return `long` but `int`. No need to use a `long` variable inside the for loop.